# How to run multiple nodejs version on a single server?

Tags: node.js, server, migration, apache2, ubuntu-18.04

I want to run multiple NodeJs versions on a single system.
For EX:- I have two nodejs apps. One app are running nodejs version 10.xx.xx and another one is running nodejs version 12.xx.xx.
here I want to move both apps on a single server.
how is it possible..??

Comment: You could setup virtual machine for each app with a specific version of Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

Package each app using Docker Container then each app will have his own nodeJS version without issues because of the isolation.

You'll find official nodeJS continer in here https://hub.docker.com/_/node/